# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getRootNode' of undefined

Tags: extjs

I get this error above when trying to use a tree panel in my view. Here is the code below;

List.js

```
Ext.define('AM.view.main.List', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias: 'widget.adminlist',

requires: [
    'Ext.tree.*',
    'Ext.data.*'
],
xtype: 'tree-xml',

title: 'Admin Functions',
useArrows: true,
store: 'Admin',
initComponent: function() {
    this.items = [
        {
            title: 'Admin Functions',
            useArrows: true
        }
    ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

I have tried several variations but still get the same error. Here is the store code below;

Admin.js

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Admin', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

root: {
    expanded: true,
    children: [
        {
            text: 'app',
            children: [
                { leaf:true, text: 'Application.js' }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'button',
            expanded: true,
            children: [
                { leaf:true, text: 'Button.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Cycle.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Split.js' }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'container',
            children: [
                { leaf:true, text: 'ButtonGroup.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Container.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Viewport.js' }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'core',
            children: [
                {
                    text: 'dom',
                    children: [
                        { leaf:true, text: 'Element.form.js' },
                        { leaf:true, text: 'Element.static-more.js' }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'dd',
            children: [
                { leaf:true, text: 'DD.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DDProxy.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DDTarget.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragDrop.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragDropManager.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragSource.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragTracker.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragZone.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragTarget.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragZone.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Registry.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'ScrollManager.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'StatusProxy.js' }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'core',
            children: [
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.alignment.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.anim.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.dd.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.fx.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.position.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.scroll.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.style.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.traversal.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Helper.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Query.js' }
            ]
        },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Action.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Component.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Editor.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Img.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Layer.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'LoadMask.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'ProgressBar.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Shadow.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'ShadowPool.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'ZIndexManager.js' }
    ]
}
});
```

The controller code is also shown below;

Users.js

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
stores: [
    'Users'
],
models: ['User'],
views: [
    'main.Body',
    'main.List',
    'user.List',    
    'user.Edit'
],
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'mainbody > userlist': {
            itemdblclick: this.editUser
        },
        'useredit button[action=save]': {
            click: this.updateUser
        }
    });
},

editUser: function(grid, record) {
    var view = Ext.widget('useredit');

    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},

updateUser: function(button) {
var win    = button.up('window'),
    form   = win.down('form'),
    record = form.getRecord(),
    values = form.getValues();

record.set(values);
win.close();
// synchronize the store after editing the record
this.getUsersStore().sync();
}
});
```

Also see the view where it is referenced below;

Body.js

```
Ext.define('AM.view.main.Body' ,{
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias: 'widget.mainbody',

layout: 'border',
title: 'Administrator Profile',
width: 500,
height: 300,
store: ['Users', 'Admin'],
items: [{
    title: 'South Region is resizable',
    region: 'south',     // position for region
    xtype: 'panel',
    height: 100,
    split: true,         // enable resizing
    margins: '0 5 5 5'
},{
    // xtype: 'panel' implied by default
    region:'west',
    xtype: 'adminlist',
    margins: '5 0 0 5',
    width: 200,
    collapsible: true,   // make collapsible
    id: 'west-region-container',
    layout: 'fit'
},{
    title: 'Center Region',
    region: 'center',     // center region is required, no width/height specified
    xtype: 'userlist',   //this is displaying the gridview
    layout: 'fit',
    margins: '5 5 0 0'
}]
});
```

Can someone please help me quick I am running out of ideas.
Thank you.

Comment: You have both `alias` and `xtype` specified in `Ext.define` for your tree... not sure if that is a problem or not.  When are you getting the error?  Before anything is ever rendered?

Comment: Yeah i see that (alias and xtype). it is not an issue though. Yes the error happens before anything is rendered. I have a feeling though it is from List.js that is causing the error but i can't seem to figure it out. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things...

1. You have not included the `Admin` store in your controller.  `store` is required for a `Tree`, so if that reference is failing then that could be the issue.
2. You are adding `items` to your `tree` in `initComponent`, which doesn't make sense.  Your config for the tree is already in `Ext.define`, so setting `this.items = ...` is adding a new, nested item inside the tree panel.  This is not what you want.
3. As mentioned in my comment, don't use both `alias` and `xtype` in `Ext.define`.

If you don't need any specific extra functionality added to your tree (which your current code suggests), and you are only using it once (not sure if this is the case), you could also just use a single instance of a `tree` without defining a separate class for it:

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    store: 'Admin',   //still make sure this is defined in controller or "requires" config
    useArrows: true,
    title: 'Admin Functions',

    region:'west',
    margins: '5 0 0 5',
    width: 200,
    collapsible: true,   // make collapsible
    id: 'west-region-container',
    layout: 'fit'
}
```

Comment: Thank you kevhender. No 1 is the reason it wasn't displaying. i don't know how I missed that. For no 2, you are also right. It was when i was trying to figure out what the actual issue was. However I want to use it to do other things when the user clicks it. It will eventually take its place. No 3 is also right I have taken out the xtype. You are definitely right on all counts. Thanks a million.

Comment: How do I make the arrows from the tree show for a user to know there are children under it?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special for that, as long as the store is correctly populated...

Comment: Thanks but its not showing still and it is correctly populated. In the examples there is an arrow, then folder icon beside the fields but none of it shows in mine. Its all about making it easy for the use to see